# Concourse resource is not used error message

Tags: github, concourse

I have a concourse pipeline that bumps a semver, publishes a release to a GitHub-release resource and publishes a message using a slack-notification resource.  All is fine until I try to start using on_failure: and on_success: steps.

I moved the slack put to on_success without issue.  But when I try to move the GitHub-release put to on_success  set-pipeline returns the error:

resource 'github-release' is not used

I tried putting it in both on_failure and on_success but I still get the message.

Is there a way to only publish this release when the build is good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `on_success` and `on_failure` only run a single `step` of a pipeline. If you want to run multiple steps, you have to use one of the block `steps`, such as `do` or `aggregate` to accomplish this.

For example:

```
on_success:
  do:
    - put: slack-notification
    - put: github-release
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to learn all this... not sure why I need the do:  it seems like the identation underneath on_success: would have described that.